# Tap gestures on an element in a UITableView custom cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

This topic has been covered over and over, but after two days of researching and trying all of the solutions suggested, I still can't do what I want.

First of all, I'm creating an app for iOS 5, using storyboard.

I have a UITableViewController, with 2 types of cell (an original "message", and a number of "answers" to it). I created my table in my storyboard, checked "prototypes cells", designed 2 cells with my 2 or 3 labels, a textView, and an image. Then, I subclassed `UITableViewCell` with 2 new classes, which I called `ThreadAlertCell` and `ThreadAnswerCell`. I created properties for my cell's elements, so I can set the text of the labels and the image programmatically. I linked my graphic elements to their definition in the storyboard as usual. In my TableViewController, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I create the cells and populate them. So far so good, everything is displayed correctly and how I want it.

But, I want a "touch" on the image of a cell, to pop a new view, showing the user's profile page (an other basic view, I can do it with performSegue, no problem for that).

I have tried so many things I'm not sure it's very useful to put everything in detail here. While looking for answers, I understood that using a `UIImageView` when you expect to handle gestures is not really the best way. So I changed it to a `UIButton`. But I can't get the touch event to do anything !

I'll give only the example of an "answer" cell.

Here is my **ThreadAnswerCell** header file (I won't give the .m, nothing interesting there) :

```
@interface ThreadAnswerCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *senderLabel;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *contentTextView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *senderButton;

@end
```

And here is half the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from my **TableViewController** (I do the same for the "message" before that) :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ThreadAnswerCell";
    ThreadAnswerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ThreadAnswerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    Message *message = [threadArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.senderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", message.sender];
    cell.contentTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", message.content];
    cell.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", message.date];
    //[cell.senderButton setBackgroundImage: [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString: message.userPic]]
    //                             forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    [cell.senderButton addTarget:self action:@selector(firstButtonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    CGRect frame = cell.contentTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height = cell.contentTextView.contentSize.height;
    cell.contentTextView.frame = frame;
    [cell.contentTextView sizeToFit];

    return cell;
}
```

As you can see, I use my custom cell, then populate it with content (I use three useless `stringWithFormat` but I have my reasons, lol), and I try to add an event to my button. I also commented the part where I set the button's background image to "see" the button on my screen.

And here is the method I want the buttons to call :

```
- (void)firstButtonSelected: (id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"hello");
}
```

But, the method is never called ! Any ideas on where I've gone wrong or any other working solution would be great ! Thanks.

Comment: I tried to simulate your code and it works perfectly, try to post the code of the cell where is the button to see if you make a mistake there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Mert actually found my mistake, which was not in the code but in my storyboard where I designed my cell, I disabled UserInteraction (on purpose), thinking I could enable it only for my image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have 
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Implemented in your tableview delegate class?

I think, your cell catches the touch events. Try to delete the method. And 
`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`

Comment: Yup, it's detailed in my question. I already set the prototype cell to be **not** userInteractionEnabled, so I don't think doing this would change anything ?

Comment: Woops, sorry, I read "cellForRowAtIndexPath". Yes, I do have "didSelectRowAtIndexPath", but it's empty as I don't want any actions on touching the cell. Is that a problem ?

Comment: It makes clear why you do not get touch events. setting userInterationEnabled makes the subviews (in your case button) does not get the touch events. Just turn it to yes and instead set selection style of the cell to none.

Comment: Well, that's perfect. I really thought I could disable the UserInteraction on the cell, and enable it on any subview.. My mistake ! Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the topmost view? Make sure you add the senderButton view last to the cell view.
It's possible any other view gets touched.

Comment: Well, nothing seems to overlap my button. And I in fact added it last to my cell so I guess it's on top...